# How to set different prices for online and instore?

Tags: pricing

I sell products on my store website, on ebay and in a physical store. I would like to discount online products as compared to my store products so I tried to use special pricing - but that reduces the price for everything. Is there a way to reduce the price online but keep the same price for checking goods out when customers are physically in the store?

Comment: Great question - would love to know the answer

Comment: have you using thirdparty api or custom module for this? can you share M2E module name?

Comment: Anyone with experience please let me know. Could group pricing be the solution?